# lua http.get body for a php file, returning the code of the site not the body

Tags: javascript, php, html, http, lua

Im trying to make steam converter api on my site.
I will leave the converter file in google drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OknTaGJIKMFcHUSRI-WMSy030GAvRIyg/view?usp=sharing
So the in my lua file i use

```lua
local get = http.send("https://link-here.com/converter.php?steam_id=12345679012", "GET")
print(get.body())
```

*Output:*
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFo71.png)
but when i use it for example a raw link for github stuff
it is fine.

I hope i could describe it right, and sorry for my bad english.
Thanks.